# Tab field formatter for Entity Reference field?

Tags: entities

I'm looking for similar module to this: [Reference Tabs](https://drupal.org/project/references_tabs)
but to work with the  [Entity Reference module](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference)

The Reference Tabs module works with the [References](https://drupal.org/project/references) module, I need the same functionallity but for the   [Entity Reference module](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference)

If there is no module for this, then: can I get this with the [Field formatter settings](https://drupal.org/project/field_formatter_settings) using UI jquery tabs?

Answer (score 1):

You can find this functionality in my sandbox.

https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/legolasbo/2383347

Please submit issues if you find any.